Stereo based digital Microphone in Intel PCH [DMIC] -- Working in windows but not in Linux- Reg
Under the ACPI header of our BIOS, we have added the NHLT bins for DMIC in SSP endpoints as per our system configuration.
Consider the BIOS-stiched bins are based on stereo-based DMIC function.
Following the installation of the Windows inf-based driver, the DMIC functions flawlessly and can be located in the device manager string with the microphone array. The sensitivity appears to be adequate in Windows OS.
However, when we check, the stereo-based DMIC function in Linux 24.04 and 22.08 does not function in any version.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
The Alsa tool was installed to analyse the sound card, and the device detected on our platform appears to be functioning properly.
Input devices are available in Linux but not working in stereo-based mode.
